# Return Array from Back End to Front End

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]  
public Array loaddata()    
string sql = "SELECT Name,Time,Inuse FROM table4";    
using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection((@"Data Source")))    
{    
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, Connection))    
    {    
        Connection.Open();    
        using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())    
        {    
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();    
            dt.Load(myReader);    
            Connection.Close();    
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);    
            dv.RowFilter = (("Name='ACVX'"));    
            var tableEnumerable = dv.ToTable().AsEnumerable();     
            var tableArray = tableEnumerable.ToArray();    
            return tableArray ;   
        }    
    }    
}    

//Front End  

<html>  
<head/>  
<script>  
 PageMethods.loaddata(LoadSucc, LoadFail);  
           function LoadSucc(obj) //obj is array returned from back end{obj-tablearray]  
           {  
               var goog = [];  
               goog = Object.values(obj);  
            //I want load the obj into my array goog.  
           }  

           function LoadFail() {  
               alert("Data missing");  
           }  
script>  
<body/>  
<html>
```

I want to Load my data table content to array and return array to front end using page methods.I tried somethingbut it won't working.What's wrong with My Code?
Suggest me some Ideas

Comment: have you Debug in chrome console the obj in the function? is it empty? sometimes it wrap the response in a  data fields so you have to do something like obj.data..

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try to call your webmethod with Jquery ajax funtion like this:

```
<html>  
<head/>  
<script>  



       $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/yourpagename.aspx/loaddata",
                                data: "",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    var dataArray = $.map(data, function (item) {
                                        return item;
                                    });
                                    alert(dataArray);
                                    console.log(dataArray);
                                },
                                error: function (data) {
                                    alert("ajax error " + data);
                                }
                            });

script>  
<body/>  
<html>
```

Comment: Sorry ,I couldn't understand this concept .Can you please explain once again ?

Comment: You're trying to call your back end service not with ajax and Jquery (javascript) ... waht i suggest to you (i remember when i worked with WebMethod and WebForms) is to try to call these WebMethod Services (on back end) from a javascript front end  ..maybe with Jquery

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: Can you please post ajax example for my code ?Thanks in advance